# Change marker icon on mouseover/mouseout in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, markers, icon

I have a map made with Javascript, on which there are numerous points and each one of them has a specific png marker.
I managed to display all the markers correctly with the following code:

```
var studios_marker = L.geoJSON(studios, {
    onEachFeature: mouse_events_studios,
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng){
var smallIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: ''+ features.properties.Name +'.png',
    iconSize: [50, 40],
    iconAnchor: [15,15]
});
        return L.marker(latlng, {icon: smallIcon});
}
}).addTo(map);
```

`features.properties.Name` is the attribute field in my GeoJSON file where the names of the points are stored.

My problem is that I need to take the `var smallIcon` part out of `var studio_marker`, as I'm going to need it for mouse actions, as followed. The aim is to change the marker to a new one when the mouse is over a given feature, and then replace it back with the original one, `studioicon`. But whenever I make my `smallIcon` stand alone, I get the error

> "features is not defined"

What am I missing ?

```
var studioicon= L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'cinema.png',
    iconSize: [30, 30],
    iconAnchor: [15,15]
    });

var studios_marker = L.geoJSON(studios, {
    onEachFeature: mouse_events_studios,
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng){
        return L.marker(latlng, {icon: studioicon});
}
}).addTo(map);

var smallIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: ''+ features.properties.Name +'.png',
    iconSize: [50, 40],
    iconAnchor: [15,15]
});

function mouse_events_studios(feature, marker){
    marker.on('mouseover', function(alter_style){
        var leaflet_obj2 = alter_style.target;
        marker.setIcon(smallIcon);
    });
    marker.on('mouseout', function(origin_style){
        var leaflet_obj3 = origin_style.target;
        marker.setIcon(studioicon)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with your approach is that if you create icon outside `pointToLayer` function, `feature.properties.Name` is not defined at the time of icon creation (fact is, that your `features.properties.Name` wouldn't work even inside the function, since parameter name is `feature`, not `features`).

Solution is to create feature's small icon inside `pointToLayer` function (as you did initially), but not use it immediately, just save it for later as some custom property of the marker, let's say `smallIcon` (name can be any, as long it does not conflict with standard Leaflet marker properties).

So code could then look something like this:

```
var studioicon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'cinema.png',
  iconSize: [30, 30],
  iconAnchor: [15,15]
});
    
var studios_marker = L.geoJSON(studios, {
  onEachFeature: mouse_events_studios,
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng){
    var smallIcon = L.icon({
      iconUrl: ''+ feature.properties.Name +'.png',
      iconSize: [50, 40],
      iconAnchor: [15,15]
    });
    var marker = L.marker(latlng, {icon: studioicon});
    marker.smallIcon = smallIcon;
    return marker;
}
}).addTo(map);

function mouse_events_studios(feature, marker){
  marker.on('mouseover', function(alter_style){
    var leaflet_obj2 = alter_style.target;
    marker.setIcon(marker.smallIcon);
  });
  marker.on('mouseout', function(origin_style){
    var leaflet_obj3 = origin_style.target;
    marker.setIcon(studioicon);
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining! Been searching for hours and now it works perfectly.